# Updating a file containing an array of structures in C

Tags: arrays, c, file, struct, fseek

I need to change only one element of an `int` array in a structure array and "update" it into the folder.
Here is my code:

This is the structure

```
typedef struct studenti
    {
        char index[10];
        char ime[20];
        char prezime[20];
        int kviz[10];
    } studenti;
```

My main

```
int main(){
    studenti student[120];
    pretraga(file, student);
}
```

Function

```
void pretraga(FILE *file, studenti student[120])
{
    int odabir;
    int unos;
    int bodovi;
    int index;
    char s[20];
    fopen("studenti_2022.txt", "r+");

    printf("Unesite prezime:");

    scanf("%s",s);
    for(int i = 0; i < 120; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(student[i].prezime,(s))==0)
        {
            printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", student[i].index, student[i].ime, student[i].prezime);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                printf("%d ", student[i].kviz[j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    fopen("studenti_2022.txt", "r+");
    do
    {
        printf("Da li zelite urediti kviz(1-DA, 0-NE)?");
        scanf("%d", &odabir);
        if(odabir == 1){
            do
            {
                printf("Unesite koji kviz zelite urediti: ");
                scanf("%d", &unos);
                index = unos - 1;
                if(unos > 0 && unos < 11)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        printf("Unesite broj bodova: ");
                        scanf("%d", &bodovi);
                        if(bodovi > 0 && bodovi < 21)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                            {
                                if(j == index)
                                {
                                    for(int i = 0; i < 120; i++)
                                    {
                                        if(strcmp(student[i].prezime,(s))==0)
                                        {
                                            student[i].kviz[index] = bodovi;
                                            printf("\n\n%d\n\n", student[i].kviz[j]);
                                            fseek(file, sizeof(student[i].kviz[j]), SEEK_CUR);
                                            fprintf(file, "%d", student[i].kviz[j]);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }else
                        {
                            printf("Greska !\n");
                        }
                    }while(bodovi < 0 || bodovi > 20);
                }else
                {
                    printf("Greska pri unosu !\n");
                }
            }while(unos < 0 || unos > 10);
        }else if(odabir == 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }while(odabir < 0 || odabir > 1);

    fclose(file);
}
```

Do you have any tips what I could change, or maybe another way of doing it? I am new to this so I am open for suggestions. And the file has to remain the same (by the looks of it) I only need to be able to change 1 number in the `int` array `kviz` and write it on the place where the number was changed.

This is how the file looks like. The red mark is an example as if I wanted to change that number to 18.

Hope you understood what I wanted to say.

Also, the `char s` is used for user input to compare a string and display the whole structure of the student. And then I need to change from that specific student an element of `int kviz`

Comment: `Indenting is good. But it  is   possible    to     have      too       much.`

Comment: Learning about file IO would certainly help. There are *tons* of things wrong in this code. The leakage of `FILE*` alone is bad enough. The comparison of console-input data against indeterminate array content that came from nowhere is as-bad/worse. The origins of `file` in `main` would certainly be an added bonus to your code.

Comment: It seems that you ignore the result of `fopen()`.

Comment: In pointer heavy code, it's a good practise to always run it with Valgrind. I suspect some leaks in this code. It's just normal human mistakes. I am not saying there are leaks, I'm just saying there might be. Run with Valgrind to come to a conclusion, if you haven't already.